# ARM SoC processor and the PC host: how to program the board Xilinx ZU28 FPGA

Tags: arm, soc

I am still confused by this ARM SoC stuff. Let's say I have an ARM SoC zync7000 (Xilinx ZU28 FPGA), and I am trying to run a project on the board.

Then, I could just use my PC host to program FPGA. Therefore, I don't need ARM SoC at all.

Could somebody give out an example that ARM SoC is used? In any cases, this ARM SoC board needs to connect to a PC for any operations. Is this ARM SoC design redundant?

Comment: *"Then, I could just use my PC host to program FPGA. Therefore, I don't need ARM SoC at all."* -- Okay, so you don't use the SoC to *program* the FPGA.  But what functionality did you program into the FPGA?  When this programmed FPGA *operates* doing whatever (i.e. its real task), would having a dedicated processor (i.e. the *"redundant"* SoC) attached to it have any benefit (e.g. communicate with the outside world)?  IOW do you want a (self-contained) embedded system or a PC peripheral?

Comment: “In any cases, this ARM SoC board needs to connect to a PC for any operations.” - You only need a PC in order to program the FPGA.  After you program the FPGA it will run the program by itself.  An example of that is the FPGA controller for a ASIC Bitcoin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a block diagram of the SoC zynq7000:

[image: Block diagram of Soc zynq7000 from https://www.xilinx.com/content/dam/xilinx/imgs/block-diagrams/zynq-mp-core-dual.png]

The FPGA part is the yellow "Programmable Logic" near the bottom. Sure, if the FPGA has enough gates for it, you might implement Bitcoin network communication entirely within it, and perhaps entirely skip the ARM processor cores.

But it might be significantly easier to use an existing operating system kernel (any embedded-capable operating system) on the ARM processor cores for implementing things that are not critical for Bitcoin performance, like Ethernet + TCP/IP network protocol stacks.

Then you could dedicate the FPGA for the actual Bitcoin calculations only, which would massively simplify the FPGA programming task and also would give you more FPGA capacity usable for the actual payload.